# Android:Youtube Player

Tags: android, html, video, youtube

I Would like to know if all android-powered devices have an embeded youtube video player because i would like to play youtube videos from webview using javascript interface by passing vnd intent,i got difficult playing youtube videos inside my webview .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For apps which have Google Play Services they can support the youTube app, so you can instantiate it from your app using the new APIs - https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

There is also an iFrame API (requires HTML5 support) https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and a Javascript API (requires the browser supports Flash) https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference